# How can I make the badge notification only appear for specific tab only

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

How can I make the badge notification only appear for specific tab only when mapping in react

Here is my following code

```
<div className="team-management-tab-items">
                {tabs.map((tab, index) => (
                  <div
                    id={editable === true ? "" : `${tab}`}
                    className={
                      activeTab === index
                        ? "team-management-tab-item selected"
                        : "team-management-tab-item"
                    }
                    key={tab}
                    role="button"
                    tabIndex={tab}
                  >
                        {tab !== "Sub-Team" && (
                          <Badge
                            color="error"
                            badgeContent={1}
                            max={99}
                            variant="default"
                          >
                            <span className="tab-item-text">{tab}</span>
                          </Badge>
                        )}
                    )}
                    <span className="tab-item-indicator" />
                  </div>
                ))}
              </div>
```

[image]

Comment: I think you already have the correct logic. `{ tab !== "sub-team" && ....  }`. That is the way to go about it. One more scalable way maybe to have an array of objects, with each object having tab info like `label`, `showBadge` and other properties which you may add in future.

Comment: How can I do the other way ?

Comment: Do you mean to ask the second approach using `showBadge` property that I have mentioned?

Comment: Yes, the second approach

Comment: Hi @nathan, as it was a big code, I opted to post the answer, please upvote/accept in case it suits your use case. Thanks. Also `clsx` library might be of some help to add dynamic class names, if you want to check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have done it the right way currently, you could still make more changes if you want to make it more configurable and scalable. Again, it might not be best suited for your use case maybe, but having a configuration driven approach in this case can make it possible to add more properties in the future.

```js
const TAB_CONFIG = [
  {
    label: "Mission",
    id: "mission",
    showBadge: true,
    disabled: false
  },
  {
    label: "Agreement",
    id: "agreement",
    showBadge: true,
    disabled: false
  },
  {
    label: "Calendar",
    id: "calendar",
    showBadge: true,
    disabled: false
  },
  {
    label: "Members",
    id: "members",
    showBadge: true,
    disabled: false
  },
  {
    label: "Sub-Team",
    id: "sub-team",
    showBadge: false,
    disabled: false
  }
]

// please use a better name, gave this name just for help
const TabsComponent = () => {

  // logic to render badges
  const renderBadge = (count) => (
    <Badge
      color="error"
      badgeContent={1}
      max={99}
      variant="default"
    >
      <span className="tab-item-text">{count}</span>
    </Badge>
  )

  // logic to render tabs
  const renderTabs = () => {
    return TAB_CONFIG.map(({ label, id, showBage, disabled }) => (
      <div
        id={editable === true ? "" : `${id}`}
        className={
          activeTab === id
            ? "team-management-tab-item selected"
            : "team-management-tab-item"
        }
        key={id}
        role="button"
        tabIndex={tab}
      >
        {showBadge && renderBadge(id)}
        <span className="tab-item-indicator" />
      </div>
    ))
  }

  return (
    <div className="team-management-tab-items">
      {renderTabs()}
    </div>
  )

}
```